# How to retrieve department info of current user creating a new list item?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property

I'm building an Issue Tracking System in Sharepoint 2010 and I want to save user's department along with the other issue data.

Perhaps I don't have to save the department info. Maybe I can display it in the list view, but how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a person group column set to display as Department.  On item creation you can use some jquery/javascript to set that field to the current user or after it's created, you can update the field to the created by person using a workflow.